# UWP change Ellipse Width height by selecting its stroke

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an ellipse in UWP XAML, I want to increase and decrease its width height by selecting its stroke.
and this should be smooth, please suggest, 
//XAML code

```
 <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
    <Ellipse x:Name="DifficultyPath" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="4,4"
                 Width="250"
                 Height="250"   
                 Visibility="Visible"
                 PointerEntered="DifficultyPath_PointerEntered"
                 PointerExited="DifficultyPath_PointerExited"
                 PointerPressed="DifficultyPath_PointerPressed"
                 PointerReleased="DifficultyPath_PointerReleased" 
                 PointerMoved="DifficultyPath_PointerMoved"
                 />
</Grid>
```

//code behind   mousePressedPoint where i am taking position of clicked

```
private void DifficultyPath_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var diffPath = e.OriginalSource as Ellipse;
        Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;
        if (diffPath !=null && diffPath.Name== "DifficultyPath" && ptr !=null)
        {

            if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
            {
                Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);
                if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
                {
                    //Handle button press
                    mouseNewPoint = ptrPt.Position;
                    var offset = GetDistance(mouseNewPoint.X,mouseNewPoint.Y, mousePressedPoint.X, mousePressedPoint.Y);
                    Debug.WriteLine(offset);                        
                    DifficultyPath.Width += offset;
                    DifficultyPath.Height += offset;
                }
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused about "changing width and height of Ellipse by selecting its stroke", do you mean when you choose the whole Ellipse and then drag it by using mouse to change its size? How do you select its stroke? Can you show some code snippet about what you have achieved currently and describe your expected behavior in more details?

Comment: I have updated code, basically, my logic is once user pressed on stroke i am capturing presses point, on the move i found new mouse position and subtract->Now trying to increase width height of ellipse

Comment: It sounds feasible and what is the issue you are currently experiencing? Can you describe the unexpected behavior and provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? The code snippet is not complete, so we can't reproduce it.